# Переводчики - на помощь пожалуйста!

Tags: переводы

Оригинал: *Однажды зимним днем она стала закрывать балконное окно, **прежде чем буря могла разбить его.***
Перевод: *Однажды зимним днем она стала закрывать балконное окно, **чтобы его не разбило ветром.***

Мне надо прокомментировать то, что в оригинале стоит временное придаточное, в то время как переводчик предпочел придаточное следственное. 
Сама к сожалению объяснить не могу... Помогите пожалуйста!

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переводчик прав: по-русски так не сказали бы о ещё не разбитом окне. Поэтому явный подстрочник (вероятно, с английского: before it could be broken by the storm и т.п.) преобразован так, как сказал бы в той же ситуации носитель русского языка. В русском понимании "буря" - сложное явление, окно может разбить "порыв ветра во время бури", но вряд ли сама буря. Поэтому оправдан и выбор слова "ветер". Задачей перевода является правильная передача смысла, а не воспроизведение сходных для двух языков грамматических конструкций, что далеко не всегда возможно или полезно для результата перевода.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо большое большое!!! помогли!!!!!!! : )